# re-sizing the items inside tab panel (Tab control)

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabpanel

I want to set my tab headers to fit exactly depending on the number of tabs inside my control

so if I have 1 tab item it will expand to the whole width of the control;
if I have 2 tab items each is set to half width of the control;
3 tab items.....1/3.....etc.

any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the `Width` to the `TabControl.ActualWidth` and `TabControl.Items.Count` using a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and add a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.converter.aspx) to calculate the appropriate fraction.